# Initialize Java Object array element with 2D double array literal

Tags: java

For a certain API [1], arrays of data have to be passed as elements of a Java `Object` array (one such element per array).  The following works fine, and the 2D double array `AInData` is accepted by the API as the 1st argument (and there is only 1 argument):

```
double[][] AInData = {{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}, {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}};
Object[] arObj = { AInData };
```

Since [floating point literals default to `double`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/literals-in-java), I thought I could do without the intermediate variable `AInData`:

```
Object[] arObj = { {{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}, {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}} };
```

This caused the following errors:

```
illegal initializer for Object
Object[] arObj = { {{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}, {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}} };
                   ^
illegal initializer for <none>
Object[] arObj = { {{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}, {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}} };
                    ^
illegal initializer for <none>
Object[] arObj = { {{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}, {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}} };
                                     ^
```

**Why can I not do away with `AInData`?**

If literals truly default to `double`, then there is no casting when `AInData` is initialized.

NOTES:

[1] [Interface to Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/java/passing-arguments-to-and-from-java.html#bqqkpvp-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can

```
Object [] arObj = new double [][][] {{{1.1, 1.2, 1.3}, {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}} };
```

Comment: Thanks....can you please explain what is happening in my original code from a semantic perspective?  I thought that an literal array of *anything* is delineated by curly braces, with array elements separated by commas.  By that logic, the literal 2D `double` array should have become the first (and only) `Object` element in the array. I don't understand why it's necessary to created a 3D `double` array.

Comment: Furthermore, it seems that the compiler disassembles the 3D array along the 3rd dimension and takes each resulting 2D array (of which there is only one) as the elements of the `Object` array.  I've not seen this behaviour described anywhere, which makes me question question whether I understand what is happenging in your code (or perhaps I'm missing a designed-for behaviour of Java when assigning arrays to arrays).

Comment: @user36800 In Java multidimensional array is just an array of arrays. Each array, also, [is an object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1). So is acceptable to cast *any* dimensional array of anything to an object array.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  But your statement looks identical to mine except for `new double [][][]`. From the half dozen tutorials I read, that should not be necessary for Java 8. I thought that maybe the leading keyword `Object` would cause the compiler to look for `Object`s on the right hand side (RHS), but the Java rule is that floating point literals default to type `double`, so without the `double [][][]`, it will find a 3D `double` array. That *shouldn't* be a problem because you explicitly designate the RHS as `double [][][]` anyway. Do you know why my code fails?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect that part of the complication here may be that there is conversion taking place here from `double[][]` to `Object`. In the examples I found online, there is no conversion. The type/class on the left hand side is the same as on the RHS.

Comment: @user36800 No, I guess it's initialization convention. Need to find proof in JLS.
My guess is:
`Object[][] acceptable = {{},{}};` `Object[] not_acceptable = {{},{}};` And RHS doesn't depend on type

Comment: [Here's rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

Comment: That's unfortunate if the assignment is disallowed by convention, because semantically seems correct (a `double[][]` is an `Object`, and hence, and element of `Object[]`).  I didn't see that such a conversion contradicts any of the rules that you cited, but thanks for the reference.  I'll just go with your syntax or retain the use of the intermediate `double[][]` variable.